# Access a variable in HTML from a .py file

Tags: python, html, django

I want to have my HTML page access a variable from a .py file.
My _version.py file is :
**version** = "1.0.0"

In my HTML page I want to read the above **version** from the _version.py and display as text.

Is there a way to do this from html without making use of the render function and using the tags {{}}.

I tried enclosing the python code within my html as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
<li> Software version: <% from adapter_manager._version import __version__ %>
                                <% print __version__ %> </li>
```

Comment: Do you use any web framework? Or are you trying to read server files from a plain HTML file?

Comment: I use Django. But Wondering if I can skip creating a view in this case. 
My question boils down to if we can read a variable from a .py file directly from an HTML file.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make this more clear? Including what templating system you are using.